# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Products table.

The number of records in the table is : 44990

In this Table I have three columns,

Column 1 - Attributes NVARCHAR(MAX)

Column 2 - Detailed-description NVARCHAR(MAX)

Column 3 - Promotion NVARCHAR(MAX)

Column 1 has Json Data,

Column 2 Has Xml Data,

Column 3 has normal text

When I try to select these three columns

select p.Promotion, P.Attributes, P.DetailedDescriptionASXml from products

**I get the following error** :

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

Answer (score 7):

The error does not arise because of an issue with the query, it mainly occurs due to an issue with the connection/network.

Edit1: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1037809-146-1.aspx

Maybe this link will help you resolve the issue.

Edit2: There is a similar thread on stackoverflow. Here is the link.

[How to avoid Sql Query Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853676/how-to-avoid-sql-query-timeout)

Comment: I have searched and I couldn't resolve the error. Please Any Help